# NPM Install to wrong directory

Tags: npm, bamboo, npm-install

Trying to use NPM install during a bamboo build and getting some odd results.
Using

```
$ npm install
```

is resulting in odd results if I let the build run the command.  If I log into the build machine and run the command manually the results are as expected.

The odd results:
Look in `node_modules` and I see all package folders; however, almost all of those folders are empty.  The only ones that are not empty are the ones that I explicitly define as dependencies in package.json.

To further confuse things.  When things work out, the `node_modules` folder has roughly 18k files for about 62MB.  When it doesn't work right, it has 40k files for 112MB.  looking at individual folders with `node_modules` is event more confusing.

Just a sampling of the package folders comparing good to bad install.

```
                     Good install           Bad Install 
 package            size / # Files        size / # Files

 JSPM              1.5MB / 945             26MB / 8,924
 gulp-jspm-build   883kb / 450           23.5MB / 10,589
 eslint            1.4MB / 292            6.6MB / 3,200
```

The last confusing part: this doesn't happen 100% of the time, but most times it does.

I realize that there may be issues with the build itself, but I'm unfamiliar with bamboo and those in charge of it are convinced it is a problem on my side.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  If you need more info, please ask.

NPM version 3.3.12
Node version 5.5.0

Comment: Thanks.  I added the versions to the question.

Comment: I have the same issue! bamboo will generate the whole project inside the node_modules redundantly! did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, never did find a solution.  And I have since moved on to another client where Bamboo is not used, so I most likely will not be investigating any further.